# Export/Backup a SQL Login's Information

Tags: sql-server, authentication, backup

I have a certain dilemma, using **SQL server 2005 and 2008**.

There's an emergency that needs to be performed, and the only way (SLA-bound) to do so is to use a certain SQL login. The problem is, the person who has the password can't be reached, and we soon need to perform the update (through an application and using scripts and ssis).

*The current discussion is to change the password and then revert back to the original.*

So, is this possible? To export or backup the SQL login? (Coz if so, then we can indeed easily change the password, perform the update, then restore the original one)

```
For this scenario, kindly assume that we need to backup the 
SQL login's info (including the password)
```

Comment: Good question. If you don't get an answer here, you might try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can script out the login with a password hash. Then do what you need to do and finally drop the login and recreate it using the script. There are several articles out there describing how to do the scripting step, e.g.: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/billg/archive/2010/07/08/Scripting-out-SQL-Server-Logins.aspx

However, dropping the login drops all permissions that where granted to that login. Also, there are a few things that prevent a login from being dropped, e.g. it owning a database.

So you also need to script out the permissions and temporarily reassign ownership of those logins.

It is possible that you can use the password hash to directly reset the password, but I have never tried that. If that works you would not have to do all the dropping and recreating.

Script for backing up all logins:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_hexadecimal]    ****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_hexadecimal] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
     @binvalue varbinary(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @charvalue varchar(256)
    DECLARE @i int
    DECLARE @length int
    DECLARE @hexstring char(16)
    SELECT @charvalue = '0x'
    SELECT @i = 1
    SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue)
    SELECT @hexstring = '0123456789ABCDEF' 
    WHILE (@i <= @length) 
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @tempint int
      DECLARE @firstint int
      DECLARE @secondint int
      SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1))
      SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16)
      SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16)
      SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue +
        SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) +
        SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1)
      SELECT @i = @i + 1
    END
    return @charvalue

END
GO


SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
--use MASTER
GO
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '-- Script created on ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(100))
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT ''
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '-- Create the windows logins'
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
SELECT 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.sys.server_principals WHERE [name] = ''' + [name] + ''')
    CREATE LOGIN [' + [name] + '] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' + 
        default_database_name + '], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO

'
FROM master.sys.server_principals
where type_desc In ('WINDOWS_GROUP', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN')
AND [name] not like 'BUILTIN%'
and [NAME] not like 'NT AUTHORITY%'
and [name] not like '%\SQLServer%'
GO

PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '-- Create the SQL Logins'
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
select 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.sys.sql_logins WHERE [name] = ''' + [name] + ''')
    CREATE LOGIN [' + [name] + '] 
        WITH PASSWORD=' + [master].[dbo].[fn_hexadecimal](password_hash) + ' HASHED,
        SID = ' + [master].[dbo].[fn_hexadecimal]([sid]) + ',  
        DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' + default_database_name + '], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
        CHECK_EXPIRATION=' + CASE WHEN is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.sys.sql_logins WHERE [name] = ''' + [name] + ''')
    ALTER LOGIN [' + [name] + ']
        WITH CHECK_EXPIRATION=' + 
            CASE WHEN is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ', CHECK_POLICY=' + 
            CASE WHEN is_policy_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + '
GO


'
--[name], [sid] , password_hash 
from master.sys.sql_logins 
where type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' 
and [name] not in ('sa', 'guest')

PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '-- Disable any logins'
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
SELECT 'ALTER LOGIN [' + [name] + '] DISABLE
GO
' 
from master.sys.server_principals 
where is_disabled = 1

PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT '-- Assign groups'
PRINT '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
select 
'EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N''' + l.name + ''', @rolename = N''' + r.name + '''
GO

'
from master.sys.server_role_members rm
join master.sys.server_principals r on r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
join master.sys.server_principals l on l.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
where l.[name] not in ('sa')
AND l.[name] not like 'BUILTIN%'
and l.[NAME] not like 'NT AUTHORITY%'
and l.[name] not like '%\SQLServer%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use script to backup/restore login using microsoft sql server

**Step 1:** Create sp_help_revlogin procedure

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_hexadecimal') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal
    @binvalue varbinary(256),
    @hexvalue varchar (514) OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @charvalue varchar (514)
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @length int
DECLARE @hexstring char(16)
SELECT @charvalue = '0x'
SELECT @i = 1
SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue)
SELECT @hexstring = '0123456789ABCDEF'
WHILE (@i <= @length)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tempint int
  DECLARE @firstint int
  DECLARE @secondint int
  SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1))
  SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16)
  SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16)
  SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1)
  SELECT @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @hexvalue = @charvalue
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_help_revlogin') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin @login_name sysname = NULL AS
DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @type varchar (1)
DECLARE @hasaccess int
DECLARE @denylogin int
DECLARE @is_disabled int
DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
DECLARE @tmpstr  varchar (1024)
DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

DECLARE @defaultdb sysname

IF (@login_name IS NULL)
  DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR

      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
      ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name <> 'sa'
ELSE
  DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR


      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
      ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name = @login_name
OPEN login_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
  CLOSE login_curs
  DEALLOCATE login_curs
  RETURN -1
END
SET @tmpstr = '/* sp_help_revlogin script '
PRINT @tmpstr
SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'
PRINT @tmpstr
PRINT ''
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
  IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
  BEGIN
    PRINT ''
    SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name
    PRINT @tmpstr
    IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
    BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group

      SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
    END
    ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
        -- obtain password and sid
            SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT

        -- obtain password policy state
        SELECT @is_policy_checked = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
        SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name

            SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

        IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
        END
        IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
        END
    END
    IF (@denylogin = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is denied access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
    BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    IF (@is_disabled = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is disabled
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
    END
    PRINT @tmpstr
  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
   END
CLOSE login_curs
DEALLOCATE login_curs
RETURN 0
GO
```

**Step 2:** Execute sp_help_revlogin and copy result to restore login

Reference http://giasutinhoc.vn